# DiscordJS - Embedding a random image from an array

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have a command for my DiscordJS bot that has an array of Imgur links. I want it to select a single link randomly and embed that in a message to the channel. I think I am close. How do I call it from the array?

```js
if (command == "dude") return dude(args, message); 

function dude(args, message) {
  if (args.length > 0)
    return message.channel.send(You are not using this command correctly.);
  const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed();
  var dudes = ["imgururl1", "imgururl2", "imgururl3", "imgururl4" ];
  var dude = Math.floor(Math.random() * dudes.length);
  embed.setImage([dude]);
  message.channel.send(embed);
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You just needed to access the array with the given index.

```
embed.setImage(dudes[dude]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks good, just make sure, as Kaynn said, to call the `dude` variable from the `dudes` array:

```js
dudes[dude];
```

Or, you can define dude with it altogether:

```js
var dude = dudes[Math.floor(Math.random() * dudes.length)];
```

Also, make sure to send the message within double quotes to make it a string, otherwise, the system is going to give a syntax error.